# Does Speech Framework recognize only English?

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition

I'm currently working on a project about voice recognition and translate to another language with WebAPI. English to Any Language is done, but I want to make this recognition with other language.

Does [Speech Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech) recognize only English? can I use this framework for another languages?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: show some code that you have done, only then we are able to help

Comment: Will you please explain your actual problem. So we can get a solution.

Comment: I 'm already told that. I 'm using speech framework for Voice Recognition in English and I want to do Voice Recognition in other Languages. How can i do that ? Is it possible to make it with Speech framework ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this :

```
SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.init(identifier: "vi"))
```

The `identifier` is the language you want to work with. Language designator examples :

```
//English : en
//French : fr
//Japanese : ja
//VietNamese : vi
```

Answer (score 17):

Just run `print(SFSpeechRecognizer.supportedLocales())` and you will get

> [es-419 (fixed), th-TH (fixed), ca-ES (fixed), fr-BE (fixed), de-CH
>   (fixed), sk-SK (fixed), en-ZA (fixed), es-CL (fixed), hi-IN (fixed),
>   zh-CN (fixed), zh-TW (fixed), da-DK (fixed), hi-IN-translit (fixed),
>   el-GR (fixed), he-IL (fixed), pt-BR (fixed), en-AE (fixed), pt-PT
>   (fixed), fr-CH (fixed), ro-RO (fixed), vi-VN (fixed), en-SA (fixed),
>   pl-PL (fixed), es-US (fixed), hi-Latn (fixed), en-SG (fixed), tr-TR
>   (fixed), hr-HR (fixed), ko-KR (fixed), uk-UA (fixed), it-CH (fixed),
>   ar-SA (fixed), id-ID (fixed), en-IN (fixed), es-ES (fixed), de-AT
>   (fixed), en-IE (fixed), cs-CZ (fixed), es-CO (fixed), zh-HK (fixed),
>   sv-SE (fixed), en-PH (fixed), en-ID (fixed), en-CA (fixed), nl-NL
>   (fixed), yue-CN (fixed), en-NZ (fixed), en-GB (fixed), ja-JP (fixed),
>   it-IT (fixed), ru-RU (fixed), en-US (fixed), ms-MY (fixed), es-MX
>   (fixed), hu-HU (fixed), fr-CA (fixed), wuu-CN (fixed), de-DE (fixed),
>   fr-FR (fixed), fi-FI (fixed), nb-NO (fixed), nl-BE (fixed), en-AU
>   (fixed)]

Answer (score 6):

I spent a few hours looking for a solution to get all the supported languages in a human-readable form and that's what worked for me.
First, create a model for a Language:

```
struct SupportedLanguage {
    let code: String?
    let name: String?
}
```

Next run a "for" loop in the `SFSpeechRecognizer.supportedLocales()`, create `SupportedLanguage` instances and add them to an array `availableLanguages`:

```
var availableLanguages: [SupportedLanguage] = []
for locale in SFSpeechRecognizer.supportedLocales() {
    let language = SupportedLanguage (
        code: locale.languageCode,
        name: Locale.init(identifier: "en").localizedString(forIdentifier: locale.identifier)
    )
    availableLanguages.append(language)
}
```

And that's it - you have an array of `SupportedLanguage` instances for every Speech framework supported language. Work's neatly for language selection.

Comment: should be 'var availableLanguages..'

Answer (score 5):

> Does Speech Framework recognize only English?

**No it doesn't**, as mentioned in the [Apple Speech Recognition API Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/509/)
 (02:55):

> "iOS 10 supports over 50 languages and dialects ..."

Also, adapted from the [Speech Framework Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech):

> The Speech APIs perform speech recognition by communicating with
>   Apple's servers or using an on-device speech recognizer, if available.
>   **To find out if a speech recognizer is available for a specific**
>   **language, you adopt the** [**SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizerdelegate) **protocol**.

The `SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate` protocol contains only one optional method:

[speechRecognizer(_:availabilityDidChange:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizerdelegate/1649879-speechrecognizer):

> Tells the delegate when the availability of the speech recognizer has
>   changed.

You could implement -for example- as:

```
func speechRecognizer(_ speechRecognizer: SFSpeechRecognizer, availabilityDidChange available: Bool) {
    if available {
        // you could display is as enabled in the app
    } else {
        // you could display is as disabled in the app
    }
}
```

The actual purpose of implementing this method is to trace the availability changing and if speech recognition is available, `available` would be set as `true`.

Comment: Just passed about an hour trying to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Usage for Locales
SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.init(identifier: "vi"))

//list to get all supported Locales
SFSpeechRecognizer.supportedLocales()
```